# Using BigCommerce handlebar helper split

Tags: bigcommerce

I am attempting to use BigCommerce handlebar helper {{split}} to separate the product.description and use it in different tabs. I understand how to format the split but how do I assign it in BigCommerce similar to assign in shopify's liquid?

Comment: can you provide the screenshot how you would like to show it?

Comment: I just need to know how to use {{split}} to create an array that I can put into different list elements for use in tabs content.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array helpers like {{before}} and {{after}} or {{first}} and {{last}}, and pass in your split statement as the array. For example, if you were using `<!-- split -->` to delineate the break in your product description, you could use either of the following 2 statements to get the first half:

```
{{{before (split product.description '<!-- split -->') 1}}}

{{{first (split product.description '<!-- split -->')}}}
```

There's a good explanation of this from NewLeaf Team in this forum post: https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00003ok5wtSAA/include-page-content-on-another-page-or-product